# sftp for .net c#

Tags: c#, .net, sftp

my boss has asked me to come up with a test page which can handle sftp of a file from one internal server to another.
As Ive never done this before I was wondering if anyone could give me a shove in the right direction please?

thanks

DD

Answer (score 1):

`.Net Framework` doesn't have internal support for connecting to SFTP. But there are some free libraries which can handle that - right now I am using in my project this one successfully - [SharpSSH](http://www.tamirgal.com/blog/page/SharpSSH.aspx).

Comment: .. which is unsupported, outdated and incompatible with some servers.

Comment: That's true, but it is free and it works:) I would be glad if you can recommend me another one fully freeware.